# How to fix the incompatible block pointer types sending error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode11

The Build fails because of the incompatible block pointer types sending error in xcode 11.5.

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)retrieveSourceWithId:(NSString *)identifier 
    clientSecret:(NSString *)secret 
    responseCompletion:(STPAPIResponseBlock)completion {
    NSString *endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", 
        APIEndpointSources, identifier];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"client_secret": secret};
    return [STPAPIRequest<STPSource *> getWithAPIClient:self

                                           endpoint:endpoint

                                         parameters:parameters

                                       deserializer:[STPSource new]

                                         completion:completion];

}
```

[image]

Comment: not up to date with objc but it seems you try to pass a `STPAPIResponseBlock` to a function parameter that does not match. `STAPIResponseBlock` may be a typealias of a dedicated block and the `getWithApiClient` method want another kind of block for the `completion` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the difference between two types of the block as described in the error.

You are sending

`STPAPIResponseBlock` aka `^(ResponseType, NSHTTPURLResponse, NSError)`

Expected type is:

`^(STPSource, NSHTTPURLResponse, NSError)`

The first parameter of `STPAPIResponseBlock` isn't compatible.

However it appears that this might be a [bug in the Stripe API](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/638)

Confirm you have `14.0.1` or higher of the library. That *might* fix the issue.

Comment: The issue was because of StripeAPI because the build was successful with the Xcode 11.